# Finding the biggest product of two integers formed by the digits 1-9

Tags: haskell

The question was, which is the biggest product you can make from the digits of 1 to 9 (which is 9642*87531, BTW). It is pretty clear that one number starts with 9 and the other with 8, and that you need to append the remaining digits in descending order to one or the other number.

```
buildList x y [] acc = (x,y):acc 
buildList x y (z:zs) acc = buildList (10*x+z) y zs (buildList x (10*y + z) zs acc)

list = buildList 9 8 [7,6,5,4,3,2,1] []
```

Sorting it by descending products, and taking the beginning of the list:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function
result = take 10 $ sortBy (compare `on` (negate.uncurry (*))) list
```

I'm not satisfied with my solution for `buildList`, which uses explicit recursion. I'd like to have something like a fold, just not linear but with different "branches".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick try to implement your algorithm using 'foldr'. I did not check in depth whether my solution is correct.

I have divided the problem into parts. First we define a function that takes a list and splits the list into pairs of partitions where the order of elements is preserved.

```
split :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
split []     = [([],[])]
split (x:xs) = concatMap (\(fst,snd) -> [(x:fst,snd), (fst,x:snd)]) (split xs)
```

Employing this definition we can define the list of tuples of decimals.

```
combinations :: [([Int],[Int])]
combinations = map (\(fst,snd) -> (9:fst,8:snd)) (split [7,6..1])
```

To transform these lists of decimals into numbers we use the following transformation.

```
toDeci :: [Int] -> Int
toDeci = foldl (\acc x -> x + 10 * acc) 0
```

Combining these functions we can redefine `list` as follows.

```
list :: [(Int,Int)]
list = map (\(fst,snd) -> (toDeci fst,toDeci snd)) combinations
```

Now we can define `split` by using `foldr`.

We can probably improve the code by using predefined functions like the arrow function `(***)`.

**Edit:** You can generalize `split` by using the list monad. First we defined `split` using `foldr` as follows.

```
foldr (\x -> concatMap (\(fst,snd) -> [(x:fst,snd), (fst,x:snd)])) [([],[])]
```

Now we can observe that the neutral element is `return ([],[])` in the list monad and `concatMap` is the implementation of `(>>=)`. That is, we can define `split` as follows.

```
foldr (\x xs -> xs >>= (\(fst,snd) -> [(x:fst,snd), (fst,x:snd)])) (return ([],[]))
```

This implementation can be shortened by using the predefined function `foldM` from `Control.Monad`.

```
foldM (\(fst,snd) x -> [(x:fst,snd), (fst,x:snd)]) ([],[])
```

Comment: I have to look closer at this. The "multi-fold" I'm looking for seems to be generalization of your `split`.